# Ola Hallengren DatabaseBackup error on locating Windows directory

Tags: sql-server, security, ola-hallengren

Need help in resolving the issue with backing up a DB using [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/) stored procedure to a shared folder.

I have a procedure that is executed at SQL Server startup. It runs [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/)'s `DatabaseBackup` procedure. The SQL Server service runs under `NT Service`.

The share has permissions for the machine where SQL runs.

Now, if execute `DatabaseBackup` manually it goes fine. When it executes automatically at startup it fails with the following error:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DatabaseBackup, Line 786
>   [Batch Start Line 0] The directory \\*** does not exist

If I alter the procedure with an `Execute As DBO` clause, it fails with the same error.

I also tried to `Alter` the SP with `Execute As Self` clause - the same error again.

So the question is:

What should I do to make it work?

- The file path is provided as a UNC path (e.g. `\\machine2\backup\`)
- This is SQL Express, so I don't have access to SQL Agent jobs.
- Therefore, this is a stored procedure configured to run when the SQL Server instance starts up, not a SQL job set to run when SQL Agent starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, there is a known issue with the undocumented command `xp_fileexist` that is used inside [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/)'s `DatabaseBackup` stored procedure when executed under `sa` and checks a shared folder.

There are several solutions of the issue. But I preferred to comment the block where the stored procedure is used. Now it works fine.
Special thanks to [sql.ru](http://sql.ru) forum.

Comment: Can you please show me what part of the script you commented out?

Answer (score 5):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Use a domain account with access rights on the share, then this should work. `NT_Service` will not be able to reach it.

If using a domain account is not possible for some reason, you can try granting the machine account permission to the share. The machine account follows the following format: `DOMAIN\MachineName$`. The `$` is needed to denote it's a computer and not a user.